# Using an XmlTextAttribute on an array of mixed types removes whitespace strings

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlserializer

I am writing a set of objects that must serialize to and from Xml, following a strict specification that I cannot change. One element in this specification can contain a mix of strings and elements in-line.

A simple example of this Xml output would be this:

```
    <root>Leading text <tag>tag1</tag>    <tag>tag2</tag></root>
```

Note the whitespace characters between the closing of the first tag, and the start of the second tag. Here are the objects that represents this structure:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
   [XmlText(typeof(string))]
   [XmlElement("tag", typeof(Tag))]
   public List<object> Elements { get; set; }

   //this is simply for the sake of example.
   //gives us four objects in the elements array
   public static Root Create()
   {
      Root root = new Root();

      root.Elements.Add("Leading text ");
      root.Elements.Add(new Tag() { Text = "tag1" });
      root.Elements.Add("    ");
      root.Elements.Add(new Tag() { Text = "tag2" });

      return root;
   }

   public Root()
   {
      Elements = new List<object>();
   }
}

public class Tag
{
   [XmlText]
   public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

Calling Root.Create(), and saving to a file using this method looks perfect:

```
public XDocument SerializeToXml(Root obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Serialization looks exactly like the xml structure at the beginning of this post.

Now when I want to serialize an xml file back into a Root object, I call this:

```
public static Root FromFile(string file)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));  

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(file, settings);

    //whitespace gone here
    Root root = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Root;
    return root;
}
```

The problem is here. The whitespace string is eliminated. When I call Root.Create(), there are four objects in the Elements array. One of them is a space. This serializes just fine, but when deserializing, there are only 3 objects in Elements. The whitespace string gets eliminated.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried using xml:space="preserve", as well as a host of XmlReader, XmlTextReader, etc. variations. Note that when I use a StringBuilder to read the XmlTextReader, the xml contains the spaces as I'd expect. Only when calling Deserialize(stream) do I lose the spaces.

Here's a link to an entire working example. It's LinqPad friendly, just copy/paste: http://pastebin.com/8MkUQviB The example opens two files, one a perfect serialized xml file, the second being a deserialized then reserialized version of the first file. Note you'll have to reference System.Xml.Serialization.

Thanks for reading this novel. I hope someone has some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space

Comment: and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#vc-PEinGroup

Comment: @Jodrell - assigning xml:space=preserve on either the root or tag elements doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. Workaround seems to be replace all whitespaces and crlf in XML text nodes by &#32; &#10; &#13; entities. Semantic equal entities (&#x20; &#x0a; &#x0d;) does not work.

```
<root>Leading text <tag>tag1</tag>&#32;&#32;&#32;<tag>tag2</tag></root>
```

is working for me.